# Is there a way to concat two columns from a table and join three tables

Tags: sql, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join

I am trying to join three tables, but in one of the tables I need to concat two columns for being able to do the left join.

```
select * from 
 order_dupe_check_cleaned dcc left join AAPEN_SORLIN asr
on dcc.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID = asr.VLCODE 
left join order_dupe_atributes oda on dcc.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID = oda.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID 
and oda.product_id = --** Here I want to insert the concat statement**(select concat_ws(VLDEPT,VLSTYL)as product_id2 pi from AAPEN_SORLIN) 
where dcc.order_id like '73901124'
;
```

I have used (+) instead (||) as this one was giving me duplicates, so I was trying to link the three tables by using **left join** however, one of the tables does not contain product_id but it has two columns (VLDEPT,VLSTYL) that together give the product_id that is why I wanted to use concat.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Please give a ***concrete*** example.  Enough example data for each table to demonstrate the behaviour you need, plus the full results you expect from that example data.  Please read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) and [mre]

Comment: What does the last paragraph have to do with the rest of the post? It is not clear. If it is a solution, it belongs in an answer post, not a question post. (But it's still not clear.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With strings you can concatenate simply by using ||.

Because you've already joined the fields via `left join AAPEN_SORLIN asr` you should be able to access them directly.

```
select 
    * 
from 
 order_dupe_check_cleaned dcc 
 left join AAPEN_SORLIN asr
on dcc.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID = asr.VLCODE 
left join order_dupe_atributes oda on dcc.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID = oda.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID 
and oda.product_id = VLDEPT||VLSTYL

--** Here I want to insert the concat statement**(select concat_ws(VLDEPT,VLSTYL)as product_id2 pi from AAPEN_SORLIN) 
where dcc.order_id like '73901124'
```